# What happens after -drawRect: is called within a UIView?

Tags: ios, drawrect

In one of the UIViews in my application, it seems like there is a delay after `-drawRect:` has completed before its content is presented onscreen.

Is there something that happens between the completion of drawing in `-drawRect:` and the display of the updated view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `drawRect:` method is called automatically by UIView's `drawLayer:inContext:` method. Once this happens, the drawing operations performed in `drawRect:` are rendered to the image context. The layer of the view then has its content set to this rendered image from the context.

How do you know that the delay is *after* `drawRect:` has completed? I'd suggest profiling it to be sure this is the source of your lag. Unoptimized drawing can surely be a source of delays, but don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: Do you mean the image should appear on the screen of the device as soon as the drawrect completed? Thank you, I will profile to see what's going on.:)

Answer (score 0):

All drawing updates are collected and done in the end of the operation cycle. Thus, if you notice a delay then there are other processes to be done before rendering the drawing changes. Also, drawing is a costly process.